# How to run an application with for-looping in sub directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have over 3000 sub directories that each contain a dbf file named contact2.dbf.

I'm using an application called dbview.exe to run exports from the databases based on filter conditions.  What I currently did was create a frankenscript using excel and the "copy path" function in windows to build a script and output the exports to directoryname.dbf.

Kinda sloppy now that I think about it and I could have just output them all to the same .dbf file but oh well.  I'm refining my process.

So, what I would like to do is use the `loop /R` command to specify the sub directories as new sub directories are added daily and I don't want to keep having to modify this huge script. The directories in the script below are `T:\TM5\Data\Nix`, `T:\TM5\Data\Covenant`, etc.

The script can be edited to all output to the same /EXPORT location too.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe" T:\TM5\Data\Nix\contact2.dbf /EXPORT:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\Nix.dbf /FILTER:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LEADS.flt  /COLUMNS:COM,EMAILADRES,EXTENSION,TL1,CON,TITLE,ADDRESS,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,MEM,TERMCODE,LCL,EMPLYU9,STATUS,FIRSTNAMU2,LASTNAMU4,SIC,DUNS,DUNSU6,LISTSRC
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe" T:\TM5\Data\Covenant\contact2.dbf /EXPORT:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\Covenant.dbf /FILTER:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LEADS.flt  /COLUMNS:COM,EMAILADRES,EXTENSION,TL1,CON,TITLE,ADDRESS,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,MEM,TERMCODE,LCL,EMPLYU9,STATUS,FIRSTNAMU2,LASTNAMU4,SIC,DUNS,DUNSU6,LISTSRC
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe" T:\TM5\Data\Fenyx\contact2.dbf /EXPORT:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\Fenyx.dbf /FILTER:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LEADS.flt  /COLUMNS:COM,EMAILADRES,EXTENSION,TL1,CON,TITLE,ADDRESS,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,MEM,TERMCODE,LCL,EMPLYU9,STATUS,FIRSTNAMU2,LASTNAMU4,SIC,DUNS,DUNSU6,LISTSRC
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe" T:\TM5\Data\FarmSC\contact2.dbf /EXPORT:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\FarmSC.dbf /FILTER:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LEADS.flt  /COLUMNS:COM,EMAILADRES,EXTENSION,TL1,CON,TITLE,ADDRESS,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,MEM,TERMCODE,LCL,EMPLYU9,STATUS,FIRSTNAMU2,LASTNAMU4,SIC,DUNS,DUNSU6,LISTSRC
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe" T:\TM5\Data\CMTCsola\contact2.dbf /EXPORT:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\CMTCsola.dbf /FILTER:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LEADS.flt  /COLUMNS:COM,EMAILADRES,EXTENSION,TL1,CON,TITLE,ADDRESS,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,MEM,TERMCODE,LCL,EMPLYU9,STATUS,FIRSTNAMU2,LASTNAMU4,SIC,DUNS,DUNSU6,LISTSRC
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe" T:\TM5\Data\OneDigMV\contact2.dbf /EXPORT:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\OneDigMV.dbf /FILTER:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LEADS.flt  /COLUMNS:COM,EMAILADRES,EXTENSION,TL1,CON,TITLE,ADDRESS,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,MEM,TERMCODE,LCL,EMPLYU9,STATUS,FIRSTNAMU2,LASTNAMU4,SIC,DUNS,DUNSU6,LISTSRC
```

Comment: Perhaps, `@For /D %%A In ("T:\TM5\Data\*")Do @"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe" "%%A\contact2.dbf" /EXPORT:"C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\%%~nxA.dbf" /FILTER:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LEADS.flt  /COLUMNS:COM,EMAILADRES,EXTENSION,TL1,CON,TITLE,ADDRESS,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,MEM,TERMCODE,LCL,EMPLYU9,STATUS,FIRSTNAMU2,LASTNAMU4,SIC,DUNS,DUNSU6,LISTSRC 2>NUL` is close to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is

```
for /d %%w in ("T:\TM5\Data\*") do "C:\Program Files (x86)\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe" "%%w\contact2.dbf" /EXPORT:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\Nix.dbf /FILTER:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LEADS.flt  /COLUMNS:COM,EMAILADRES,EXTENSION,TL1,CON,TITLE,ADDRESS,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,MEM,TERMCODE,LCL,EMPLYU9,STATUS,FIRSTNAMU2,LASTNAMU4,SIC,DUNS,DUNSU6,LISTSRC
```

where `%%w` should acquire the full name of each subdirectory of `T:\TM5\Data` but only of that directory, ie. one level below, non-recursive.

Comment: Magoo, take a look at my comment, you'll note that the export path is dynamic too!

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so very much.  I had the question posted on another forum as well and someone suggested using powershell.  I froze my machine trying to get it to work.  I need to learn how to use PS more but I'm just more comfortable with batch files :P  Anyhow thank everyone so much!

Comment: Yeah, i'm using the tool to export to a file right now, then another script to import the files as well.  According to the release notes of this software, your supposed to be able to copy or append data using command line as well.  I just needed the syntax so I can output directly from one .dbf to another existing dbf.  Instead of creating new files inbetween.  I'm just waiting to hear back from the vendor so I can figure out what the switches are :) now thanks to you fine people, I think I have everything I need :D

Comment: @David, please read my comments, either the code above is currently incorrect, or your question is wrong! Magoo, will surely be along soon, to modify/clarify, but in the meantime, use the code in my comment below your question.

Comment: @Compo, yep,I see that.  Yeah, your code is more like what i'm currently doing with my script and the dynamic filenames.  I'm still waiting to hear back from the software vendor so I don't have to have to export to a file and then import it with another script.  Instead, I can just copy/append the data to an existing dbf in the same script. I just need to know what switches I need to use with their software :P

Comment: The path issue could be easily fixed by replacing `Nix` with `%%~w` in the `/EXPORT` path. By the way, also in the first argument `%%~w` should be used...

Comment: Seems I'd not noticed the second instruction-variation amongst the clutter. Well, SO/batch-file is a co-operative area, unlike some other SO areas I could nominate, some of which are positively hostile. I'm curious @aschipfl about the `%%~w` recommendation. AFAIAA, `%%w` would be unquoted in a `for /d`. True, it *may* contain separators and hence *may* need to be quoted - perhaps this may be an issue? All in the cause of max-flexibility, of course.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm back again.  I've been using the command @Compo provided to pull the data out and it's been working really well!  However, I'm having an issue with this software where If I use an import *.dbf command, the memo field does not carry over.  If I specify each .dbf in a script the memo field imports just fine.  Can you fine pole please help me adjust my script so that each command is ran separately for each .dbf file in the directory again?  I'll post the script I'm using in my next comment.  This is the very last step i'm missing in my project.

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe"/APPEND:Q:\TM5\Data\trsleads\CONTACT2.DBF,C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LITTLE\databasename.dbf

Comment: I think this is close to what I need but I run the script and nothing happens.  for /R %I in ("C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LITTLE\*.DBF") Do "C:\Program Files (x86)"\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe"/APPEND:Q:\TM5\Data\dleads\CONTACT2.DBF, C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LITTLE\%I

Comment: Got it.  Sorry for all the wall of text but yeah.  This is what I needed.

For %%I in ("C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LITTLE\*.DBF") Do "C:\Program Files (x86)\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe"/APPEND:Q:\TM5\Data\dleads\CONTACT2.DBF, %%I

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer goes to Compo.  What i was trying to do was dynamically pull data from thousands of .dbf files, each in different directories using an application called dbview.

https://www.dbf2002.com/

I used Compo's script to pull out the data:

> @For /D %%A In ("T:\TM5\Data*")Do @"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\DBF Viewer
>   2000\dbview.exe" "%%A\contact2.dbf"
>   /EXPORT:"C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\%%~nxA.dbf"
>   /FILTER:C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LEADS.flt
>   /COLUMNS:COM,EMAILADRES,EXTENSION,TL1,CON,TITLE,ADDRESS,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,MEM,TERMCODE,LCL,EMPLYU9,STATUS,FIRSTNAMU2,LASTNAMU4,SIC,DUNS,DUNSU6,LISTSRC
>   2>NUL

And then this to put it all into another database:

> For %%I in ("C:\AUTOMATION\LEADS\LITTLE*.DBF") Do "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\DBF Viewer
>   2000\dbview.exe"/APPEND:Q:\TM5\Data\dleads\CONTACT2.DBF, %%I

Path's may be different because I was trying different things in different directories, but the syntax should work and can be manipulated to fit if anyone runs into a similar scenario.